# Module parse error in '.utils/utils.module' in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2.
While executing the application, after giving the npm run build command, i am getting the following error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywqgS.png) Kindly help me resolve the issue.

```
WARNING in C:/wamp/www/firesouls_frontend/~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
71:15 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in C:/wamp/www/firesouls_frontend/~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
87:15 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./app.module.ts
Module parse failed: C:\wamp\www\firesouls_frontend\config/../app\app.module.ts Unexpected character '@' (16:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import {UtilsModule} from './utils/utils.module';
|
| @NgModule({
|   imports: [
|     BrowserModule,
 @ ./main.ts 6:0-39

ERROR in C:/wamp/www/firesouls_frontend/~/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json
Module parse failed: C:\wamp\www\firesouls_frontend\node_modules\moment-timezone\data\packed\latest.json Unexpected toke
n (2:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|       "version": "2017b",
|       "zones": [
|               "Africa/Abidjan|LMT GMT|g.8 0|01|-2ldXH.Q|48e5",
 @ C:/wamp/www/firesouls_frontend/~/moment-timezone/index.js 2:15-51
 @ multi vendor
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 4 hidden modules
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! svx-frontend@1.0.0 build: `webpack --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the svx-frontend@1.0.0 build script 'webpack --progress'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the svx-frontend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --progress
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs svx-frontend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls svx-frontend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-19T11_09_13_351Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Post the text instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please upgrade your npm and node version to latest?
`npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded it to the latest versions. But getting the same error.